# GPUImageView freeze sometimes when app enters foreground

Tags: ios, ios8, freeze, gpuimage

When I updated to ios 8, GPUImageView freeze sometimes when app re-enters foreground, but it doesn't happen every time. So, I can't describe how to reproduce this error. However, this error never happened before ios 8. 
The image pipeline in my app is GPUImageVideoCamera->GPUImageHorizontalFlip->GPUImageView.

Comment: i have the same error... did you find a solution?

Comment: No. How about you? Let's ask the author.

Comment: did you get a response from him?